# How to draw equal-angle triangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to draw an equal-angle triangle (like the one below) but with small sentences instead of A, B, C

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Could you tell us what are these small sentences?

Comment: You've put the tikz tag but you're still asking how to do it?

Comment: What did you try? Where are you having problems? Set a `text width` or use the `align` key for the nodes and use manual ``\\``. `\tikz\draw(0,0)node[left]{$A$}--+(0:1)node[right]{$B$}--+(60:1)node[above]{$C$}--cycle;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tkz-euclide` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,3/0/B}
        \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center A angle 60](B)\tkzGetPoint{C}
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
        \tkzLabelPoint[above](C){Top small sentence}
        \tkzLabelPoint[below left](A){below left small sentence}
        \tkzLabelPoint[below right](B){below right small sentence}
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to increase the size of the triangle to make it bigger ?

Comment: Just add next to `\begin{tikzpicture}` the option `[scale=3]` for example or any number that makes the triangle big enough for your preference. So it will look like `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]`. You can use any number, including decimals.

Comment: Thank you Miltos

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun using Mathcha editor:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Triangle [id:dp007425499608796571] 
\draw   (301.4,53) -- (397.8,210.8) -- (205,210.8) -- cycle ;

% Text Node
\draw (160,203) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {Here\\there is another small sentence};
% Text Node
\draw (306,31) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {this is a small sentence};
% Text Node
\draw (409.41,197) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [xslant=-0.07] [align=left] {another \\ small sentences};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \draw (0,0) node[left]{this is a small sentence}
  -- (1,0) node[right]{this is another}
  -- ++ (120:1) node[above]{a final small sentence}
  -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```